# How to find the object using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

So I've used find_element_by_xpath to lacate diferent objects in the same html, using selenium.

But now I'm trying to find a specific element on the same html, always copying the xpath (chrome>inspect element>copy xpath) and I get the *NoSuchElementException* error.

The object is outside any iframe.

Heres the object that I'm trying to access:

```
<a class="carb-de-grid-name-link" data-index="1">CapLeads DataExtension_Copy</a>
```

And the whole html thing:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QfKlfYcH1y-aZ1oOZXzPwR1qeas7QjQDo0VeQOqdm-E/edit?usp=sharing

The python line:

```
link_data_extension_2=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dg-wrap"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/a')
```

I have already tried to hold the program and wait for the page to load (20s), nothing.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: that xpath has a lot of parts. It seems like it would be really easy for an extra div to sneak into the source, or one gets removed. Have you tried something less complex such as just looking for an anchor with the specified text, or with the specified class?

Comment: Html element that you mentioned '<a class="carb-de-grid-name-link" data-index="1">CapLeads DataExtension_Copy</a>' is not available in the source file shared.

Comment: @BryanOakley i'm new to xpath, have been using chrome>inspect>copyxpath with sucess so far. Will look into a closer anchor with the specified text.

Comment: When I searched that google doc for "CapLeads", it didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

To find the element with text as **CapLeads DataExtension_Copy** you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  link_data_extension_2 = driver.find_element_by_link_text("CapLeads DataExtension_Copy")
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  link_data_extension_2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.carb-de-grid-name-link")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  link_data_extension_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='carb-de-grid-name-link' and text()='CapLeads DataExtension_Copy']")
  ```

Comment: Have tried all the suggestions, all of them fail to find the element, with error "NoSuchElementExeption" and "Unable to locate the element". Definitely an issue with selenium not seeing the object in page.